# Explanation of how the code behind indexing multiple occurrences of character in a string works

Tags: java, string, indexing, netbeans

The program itself is supposed to take a string and find all the indexes of it inside another string.
Just as an example `scanner` stores data from the user, so in this case I've just written it without the use of a `scanner`:

```
String input = "asdesdu";
String largestStr = "sd";

String tempInput = input;        
while (tempInput.indexOf(largestStr) != -1) {
    int index = tempInput.indexOf(largestStr);            
    tempInput = tempInput.substring(index + 1);
}
```

So, from what I can gather the string `tempInput` is made with the same value as `input` in order for the while loop to stop running after it is run once because the value changes, however my question is why does `tempInput` also need to be used to find the `index` rather than using the original `input` string as shown below:

```
String tempInput = input;        
while (tempInput.indexOf(largestStr) != -1) {
    int index = input.indexOf(largestStr);            
    tempInput = tempInput.substring(index + 1);
}
```

I'm relatively new to java so any help or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do here, there are better ways to do it. For one, there is an overload of `indexOf` taking a start index, so you don't need to use `substring` repeatedly; for another, you could simply use `lastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the code, it searches for all occurences of `largestStr` in `input`.

`int index = input.indexOf(largestStr);` won't work here because it would always search for the occurence of `largestStr` from the beginning of `input`. So you will basically always get the same `index`.

What would work were saving the last index and searching from that index. Something like:

```
for (int index = input.indexOf(largestStr); index != -1; index = input.indexOf(largestStr, index + 1)) {
    // Do whatever you want with index
}
```